# Changing __getattr__ during instantiation

Tags: python

I am wanting to change `__getattr__` during instantiation of the class.  For example:

```
class AttrTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__getattr__ = self._getattr

    def _getattr(self, attr):
        print("Getting {}".format(attr))
```

I would have expected this to behave like:

```
class AttrTest(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print("Getting {}".format(attr))
```

But it does not.

For example, when I run:

```
>>> at = AttrTest()
>>> at.test
```

I would expect both classes to print `Getting test`, but the top class throws an `AttributeError`.

Can `__getattr__` not be changed in this way?

Comment: The response question I have is naturally, "Why??"

Comment: @WayneWerner well, I have two implementations of `__getattr__` that each use a different type of serialization (json, pickle), and I wanted my class to be able to select one at instantiation based on a kwarg.

Comment: Why not subclasses? Presumably the caller knows which is which since they're setting the kwarg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For special methods like `__getattr__`, Python searches in the base(s) `__dict__`, not in the instance `__dict__`.

You can read more details about this in the [special lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) section of the data model documentation.

> I have two implementations of `__getattr__` that each use a different
>   type of serialization (json, pickle), and I wanted my class to be able
>   to select one based on a kwarg.

This is not a good use-case for overriding `__getattr__`.  Abandon this idea, and instead consider to use [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) or [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) to handle your serialisation dynamically.

Comment: TIL... this! :)

Comment: @ballsatballsdotballs -- could you have `__getattr__` call `_getattr` which is set to `_getattrjson` or `_getattrpickle` based on the initization arguments?