# How does Python bypass normal attribute lookup to find `__dict__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, python-internals, descriptor

I understand that `__dict__`  in `obj.__dict__` is a descriptor attribute of `type(obj)`, so the lookup for `obj.__dict__` is `type(obj).__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(obj)`.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/46576009

> It's tempting to say that `__dict__` has to be a descriptor because
>   implementing it as a `__dict__` entry would require you to find the
>   `__dict__` before you can find the `__dict__`, but **Python already
>   bypasses normal attribute lookup to find `__dict__` when looking up
>   other attributes**, so that's not quite as compelling as it initially
>   sounds. If the descriptors were replaced with a `'__dict__'` key in
>   every `__dict__`, `__dict__` would still be findable.

How does "Python already bypasses normal attribute lookup to find `__dict__`"? What does "normal attribute lookup" mean?

According to the context of the quote in the link, I don't think when the author wrote that, he referred to   that the lookup for `obj.__dict__` is `type(obj).__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(obj)`.

Comment: I've noticed @Tim that that you often add a salutatory remark to your question. While this is certainly consider polite when speaking with someone face to face, it only adds noise to posts on Stack Overflow. Please see [_Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions) for further details

Comment: You may find this of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379351/changing-getattr-during-instantiation

Answer (score 6):

Normal attribute lookup is done by calling the [`__getattribute__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), or more precisely, the [C-API `tp_getattro` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro). The default implementation for this is in the [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr` C-API function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GenericGetAttr).

It is the job of `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` to invoke descriptors if they exist, and to look at the instance `__dict__`. And indeed, there *is* a `__dict__` descriptor, but it is faster for `__getattribute__` to just access the `__dict__` slot in the instance memory structure directly, and that is what [the actual implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/object.c#L1065-L1086) does:

```c
if (dict == NULL) {
    /* Inline _PyObject_GetDictPtr */
    dictoffset = tp->tp_dictoffset;
    if (dictoffset != 0) {
        if (dictoffset < 0) {
            Py_ssize_t tsize;
            size_t size;

            tsize = ((PyVarObject *)obj)->ob_size;
            if (tsize < 0)
                tsize = -tsize;
            size = _PyObject_VAR_SIZE(tp, tsize);
            assert(size <= PY_SSIZE_T_MAX);

            dictoffset += (Py_ssize_t)size;
            assert(dictoffset > 0);
            assert(dictoffset % SIZEOF_VOID_P == 0);
        }
        dictptr = (PyObject **) ((char *)obj + dictoffset);
        dict = *dictptr;
    }
}
```

Note the *Inline `_PyObject_GetDictPtr`* comment; this is a performance optimisation, as instance attribute lookups are frequent.

If you try to access `instance.__dict__` from Python code, then the descriptor is invoked; it is a data descriptor object so is invoked before instance attributes are even looked at.

Comment: Thanks. Does the lookup process for `__dict__` also apply to other attributes whose names both begin and end with two underscores, such as `__name__`, `__class__`, `__new__`, `__init__`, `__str__`, `__repr__`?

Comment: [will the lookup for self-defined attributes whose names both begin and end with two underscores (e.g. `__madeupAttribute__`)   be the same as the lookup for those special attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46594480)

Comment: @Tim: no, this isn't about special names, that `__dict__` is a special name has nothing to do with it. The attribute lookup process needs access to that specific object *every time you look up an attribute that is not a data descriptor*, so the access path is optimised.

Comment: @Tim: Special names are subject to [different lookup rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookuphttps://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup), but that happens in the code trying to access them. For example, the `hash()` function will explicitly use `type(obj).__hash__(obj)` rather than `obj.__hash__()`. It is the responsibility of the code accessing special attributes to treat them special.

Comment: @Tim: double-underscore names are "reserved", by convention only, see the [*Reserved classes of identifiers* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) of the lexical analysis documentation. You are free to make up your own, but you can't count on forward compatibility. If you want to use `__madeupAttribute__` and a future Python version wants to assign special meaning to that name, then your code could break on that Python version.

Comment: Thanks. "And indeed, there is a `__dict__` descriptor, but it is faster for `__getattribute__` to just access the `__dict__` slot in the instance memory structure directly". Do you mean that there is a `__dict__` descriptor as an attribute of the class, and there is another different `__dict__` non-descriptor attribute of the instance?  The lookup of `instance.__dict__` isn't by checking the descriptor attribute of `type(instance)`, but by looking directly at the `__dict__` non-descriptor attribute of the instance?

Comment: @Tim: no, I don't. In the end, all your data lives in different places in memory. The goal of `__getattribute__` is to get the right memory location for the instance attribute dictionary (the object that `instance.__dict__` returns), so they need a *pointer*. That pointer is stored in the memory block reserved for the instance data. `__getattribute__` could get that pointer by using the `__dict__` descriptor object; that would make the C code nice and simple. But that would not be as fast as just going to the instance memory location directly, which is what the code I linked to does.

Comment: @Tim: so rather than do `__getattribute__` -> `class.__dict__` -> *find descriptor object associated with the `__dict__` key* -> `descriptor_object.__get__(instance, class)` -> *return slot offset for instance memory region*, the much shorter path `__getattribute__` -> *slot offset for instance memory region* is used.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that the lookup for `instance.__dict__` abandons the descriptor attribute `__dict__` of `type(instance)`?  Why is `instance.__dict__` said to be the descriptor attribute of  `type(instance)`, and if so, what is the purpose?

Comment: @Tim: not sure what you mean there. The [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) only ever looks at descriptors on `type(instance)`. Since `__dict__` is a *data descriptor* the code will never look at instance attributes.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't explicit. Does this lookup process  "the much shorter path `__getattribute__` -> slot offset for instance memory region is used" not make any use of the descriptor attribute `__dict__` of `type(instance)` at all? If that is correct, why is `instance.__dict__` said to be the descriptor attribute of `type(instance)`? –

Comment: @Tim: yes, that's correct. But `__getattribute__` is not the *only user of `__dict__`*. Python code that wants to access `instance.__dict__` will still want to be able to use it, and that's where the descriptor comes in.

Comment: Thanks. When `instance.__dict__` appears in a Python program, is  `__getattribute__` always implicitly called to look up the attribute `__dict__`? If not, when is `__getattribute__`  called implicitly, and when is it not?

Comment: @Tim: `__getattribute__` is called, because there is a `.` attribute lookup there. But the descriptor is found before `__getattribute__` needs to look at instance attributes, so it is used and the result returned. If you used `instance.some_other_name` and `some_other_name` is not found on the class or not a data descriptor, *then* `__getattribute__` will get the instance attribute dictionary directly from the pointer.